# Attributes missing in SOAP response object

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I successfully exchange message with a SOAP service but for a certain message type, some attributes are missing in the deserialized response object.

The service's WSDL file is simple as all types are included from external XSD files, but the XSD files structure is quite complicated.

I've tried to simplify my example as much as possible: in the response object I get from the PHP native SoapClient, the attribute `SubAttribute` is missing for the given sample message below.

What can be done so that all attributes are correctly deserialized?

**1/** Here is the received SOAP message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope ...>
  <soap:Header>
    ...
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <MainElement MainAttribute="test">
      <SubElements>
        <SubElement SubAttribute="test">
          ...
        </SubElement>
      </SubElements>
    </MainElement>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**2/** The WSDL definition is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="ServiceName" ...>
    <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">ServiceName</wsdl:documentation>
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.example.com/Version" schemaLocation="GetMainElementMessage.xsd"/>
            ...
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message>
        <message name="GetMainElementMessage">
            <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
            <part name="Request" element="myns:GetMainElementMessage"/>
        </message>
        <message name="SetMainElementMessage">
            <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
            <part name="Response" element="myns:SetMainElementMessage"/>
        </message>
    </message>
    <portType name="ServiceName">
        <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
        <operation name="GetMainElement">
            <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Operation description.</wsdl:documentation>
            <input message="myns:GetMainElementMessage"/>
            <output message="myns:SetMainElementMessage"/>
        </operation>
        ...
    </portType>
    <binding>
    ...
    </binding>
    <service>
    ...
    </service>
</definitions>
```

**3/** The first XSD file: `GetMainElementMessage.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema ...>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="CommonAttributes.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="SubElementCommonType.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="MainElement">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="MainElementsStdAttributes"/>
            <xs:element name="SubElements" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="SubElement" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:complexContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="SubElementCommonType">
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:complexContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**4/** The second XSD file: `SubElementCommonType.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema ...>
  <xs:include schemaLocation="CommonAttributes.xsd"/>
  <xs:complexType name="SubElementCommonType">
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="SubElementsStdAttributes"/>
    ...
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**5/** And the last XSD for this example: `CommonAttributes.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema ...>
  <xs:attributeGroup name="MainElementsStdAttributes">
    <xs:attribute name="MainAttribute" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
  </xs:attributeGroup>
  <xs:attributeGroup name="SubElementsStdAttributes">
    <xs:attribute name="SubAttribute" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
  </xs:attributeGroup>
  ...
</xs:schema>
```